# Story about living gun and bullets

Tags: story-identification, games, rpg

***EDIT: This question started here, but from the comments, I was told it might be better on RPG SE.  So, I've asked it [there](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/38338/game-with-living-guns-and-bullets) as well.  I don't know if I am supposed to delete this question or what.  Mods - feel free to chime in and let me know what to do.***

This is a bit of a stretch, so I wouldn't be surprised if no one knows what I am talking about.

I recall having a conversation with a co-worker of mine over 15 years ago (around 1997-8).  He was big into Star Trek and role playing games, and although I wasn't as interested, he did mention a story that I found very interesting.  I believe the story was part of some overall historical fiction supporting a role playing game.

The game (from what I recall - I never played it) was a war/battle game where you played one species and fought against another.  Similar to what I've seen of StarCraft, although I do not believe this ran on a computer (but it may have). The species of the game were all different futuristic alien races.  Humans were there, of course, with large robotic armour to augment their infantry (kind of like the robotic vehicles from Titanfall).  I can't remember many of the other races, except there was one race whose weapons were entirely biological.  Humans used technology, but this race used living weapons which more than made up for their limitations.

Anyway, the story that accompanied this game was specifically about when the humans first encountered this species and were trying to understand them.  Somehow, they captured one of the guns that this species was using and a human psychic attempted to study it.  He bonded with the gun (which was alive and sentient) and realized that not only was the gun alive, but the bullets were alive (and sentient) too.  In order to shoot, the gun had to kill the bullet (which gives its life willingly, I think), which released energy to propel it.

The only other thing about the story I recall is that the human psychic was somehow controlled by the gun and may have been forced to shoot it at other humans near by.

Sorry for the lack of information, but I am looking forward to seeing if anyone can remember this!

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWiU_HIZ4Jc

Comment: @Richard Funny! ... but no.

Comment: Hmmm...was it a stand alone story? Or part of the literature for the game? If the latter, this might be a better fit on RPG.SE.

Comment: @JohnP Good point - I think it was literature for the game.  I will head over there.

Comment: @Trenin - It appears there already was a question on it, but if it's a better fit don't ask a new one, the mods will migrate it.

Comment: @Lohoris Yes - that is the question I created over there for the same one.

Comment: @JohnP Where is the other question?  The one referenced by Lohoris is one I created over there in response to your first comment.  Is there another question asked by someone else?  In the future, I will not migrate the question myself and let the mods do so.  Thanks!

Comment: I just linked it for future reference :)

Comment: @Lohoris OK.  I edited the question and provided a link as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're describing Tyranid weapons from Warhammer 40k - http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Tyranids

If you play computer games you've probably already heard of Warhammer 40k but maybe not know about Tyranids because the computer games had Chaos as the bad guys.

Examples of Tyranid "guns":

1. Barbed Strangler - shots seeds that grows to maturity in microseconds thereby trapping the victim in a mesh of tentacles/vines
2. Deathspitter - shots alien maggots with corrosive acid blood
3. Devourer - shots flesh eating worms
4. Fleshborer - shots flesh eating beetles

Comment: Meshes in perfectly with the description of Humans in large, powered armor.  And Psykers being unstable.